# how to select multiple elements with the same class but have diffrent data attribute to make a specific logic js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to select multiple elements with the same class but have diffrent data attribute (contains different numbers), to make logic:

**elements like this:**

```
<div class="headerCardColor" data-id="{{$card->id}}" style="border-top: 10px;">text here<div> // (data-id) is a unique number from database
<div class="headerCardColor" data-id="{{$card->id}}" style="border-top: 10px;">text here<div>
<div class="headerCardColor" data-id="{{$card->id}}" style="border-top: 10px;">text here<div>
<div class="headerCardColor" data-id="{{$card->id}}" style="border-top: 10px;">text here<div>
```

**I want when click on any above element this element shows:**

```
<div id="updateCard" data-id="{{$card->id}}" style="display:none;">
<input value="" type="hidden" class="form-control" id="cardId">
</div>
```

**and the input with id (cardId) become the data-id value of the specific element that user click on it**, I did this logic **but the issuse is:**

i want to change style of element with id (headerCardColor) that user click on it with different border-color **like this:**

```
<div id="headerCardColor" data-id="{{$card->id}}" style="border-top: 10px solid #specificColor;">text here<div> // (data-id) is a unique number from database
```

and for example when user click on second element with class (headerCardColor), its style changes with specific border-color and the old element return without this style border?

**I'll explain with images if misunderstand:**
I've elments like this:
[image]

when user click on first element, **its border-top change and another elment shows like this:**

[image]

when user click on second element i want the border-color in the second element shows and disappear from the first element and so on ?
I tried alot but noway

**my script like that:**

```
$(document).on('click', '#headerCardColor', function (e) {
e.preventDefault()
var cardId = $(this).data('id');
var idEdit = $('#cardId').val(cardId);
var cardIdEdit = $('#cardId').val()

for (const cards of document.querySelectorAll(".headerCardColor")) {
    if (cardId = cardIdEdit) {
        $('.headerCardColor').attr('style', 'border-top: 10px solid #0D67CB; background: #F5F7FA 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box; border-radius: 15px; display: grid');
    } else {
        $('.headerCardColor').attr('style', 'border-top: 10px; background: #F5F7FA 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box; border-radius: 15px; display: grid');
    }
}
$("#updateCard").show();

});
```

any idea please

Comment: Firstly, it is invalid HTML to have multiple elements with the same ID. ID should be unique per element

Comment: Can you do: `var idEdit = $(\`#cardId[data-id="${cardId}"]\`).val(cardId);` and `var cardIdEdit = $(\`#cardId[data-id="${cardId}"]\`).val()`?

Comment: should i use a class anyway i want the idea, Thanks for reply i'll try it

Comment: Or `#updateCard[data-id="${cardId} #cardId"]`, and `#headerCardColor[data-id="${cardId}"]`

Comment: Yes use classes in that case for `headerCardColor`

Comment: I tried it but also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by this approch:

```
function changeCardHeaderColor(cardIdEdit){
    $('.headerCardColor').each(function (i, obj) {
        // loop on all headerCardColor class to reset them to the default style
        $(".headerCardColor").attr('style', 'border-top: 10px; background: #F5F7FA 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box; border-radius: 15px; display: grid');
    });
    // apply new style in the class that contains specific data-id
    $(`.headerCardColor[data-id="${cardIdEdit}"]`).attr('style', 'border-top: 10px solid #0D67CB; background: #F5F7FA 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box; border-radius: 15px; display: grid');
}

$(document).on('click', '#editCard', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var cardId = $(this).data('id');
    var idEdit = $('#cardId').val(cardId);
    var cardIdEdit = $('#cardId').val()
    changeCardHeaderColor(cardIdEdit);

    $("#updateCard").show();

    $('input[name="contactsCheckboxEdit"]').each(function () {
        this.checked = false;
    });

    $.get("{{url("card/show")}}" + "/" + cardId, function (data) {
        const ids = data.contactsThatInCard;
        $('#editCardName').val(data.card.name);
        for (const checkbox of document.querySelectorAll("#contactsCheckboxEdit[name=contactsCheckboxEdit]")) {
            if (ids.includes(Number(checkbox.value))) {
                checkbox.checked = true;
            }
        }
    })
});
```